# error when checking model input using Functional API in Keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I made a data generator scheme using Keras using the following guide:

https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly

My data generator script seems to be producing numpy arrays correctly. However, when I make my model using Functional API I get the following error:

ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays:

And I don't seem to understand this error. My model takes two different input. It takes a matrix (of size 7000 x 208) as input to convolution layer and a vector (7000,) to a neural network. And these two branches are merged and given to fully connected layer followed by an output layer. This is how I've set my network:

```
ksize = 2
l2_lambda =  0.0001

i1 = Input(shape=(7000, 208))



c1 = Conv1D(128*2, kernel_size=ksize,activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(l2_lambda))(i1)
c1 = Conv1D(128*2, kernel_size=ksize, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(l2_lambda))(c1)
c1 = AveragePooling1D(pool_size=ksize)(c1)
c1 = Dropout(0.2)(c1)
c1 = Flatten()(c1)

i2 = Input(shape=(7000, ))
c2 = Dense(64,  activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(l2_lambda))(i2)
c2 = Dropout(0.1)(c2)

c = concatenate([c1, c2])

x = Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='normal',kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(l2_lambda))(c)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
output = Dense(5, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model([i1, i2], [output])

model.summary()

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
                  optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,validation_data=validation_generator)
```

And my generator script is basically generating a batch of certain size so that I don't have to load everything into the memory all at once. The script for data generation

```
class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self,list_IDs_snp,list_IDs_pos,labels,batch_size=32,n_channels=1,
                 n_classes=5,shuffle=True):
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.list_IDs_snp = list_IDs_snp
        self.list_IDs_pos = list_IDs_pos
        self.n_channels = n_channels
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.labels = labels
        self.on_epoch_end()

    def __len__(self):
        'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
        return int(np.floor(len(self.list_IDs_snp) / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        'Generate one batch of data'
        # Generate indexes of the batch
        indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]

        # Find list of IDs
        list_IDs_temp_snp = [self.list_IDs_snp[k] for k in indexes]
        list_IDs_temp_pos = [self.list_IDs_pos[k] for k in indexes]

        # Generate data
        snp,pos,y = self.__data_generation(list_IDs_temp_snp,list_IDs_temp_pos)

        return snp,pos,y

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.list_IDs_snp))
        if self.shuffle==True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

    def __data_generation(self,list_IDs_temp_snp,list_IDs_temp_pos):
        snp = np.empty((self.batch_size,7000,208))
        pos = np.empty((self.batch_size,7000))
        y = np.empty((self.batch_size),dtype=int)

        for ID in range(len(list_IDs_temp_snp)):
            snp[ID] = np.load(list_IDs_temp_snp[ID])
            pos[ID] = np.load(list_IDs_temp_pos[ID])
            y[ID] = self.labels[list_IDs_temp_snp[ID]]
        return snp,pos,y
```

This data generation scheme is same as the link I shared in the beginning.

In order to generate data I call my script as follows:

```
params = {'batch_size': 3,
          'n_classes': 5,
          'n_channels': 1,
          'shuffle': True}

training_generator = DataGenerator(partition_snp['train'], partition_pos['train'],labels, **params)
validation_generator = DataGenerator(partition_snp['valid'],partition_pos['valid'], labels, **params)
```

Do you think the problem could be that I am send partition_snp and partition_pos seperately? Partition_snp and partition_pos are just dictionaries with path to each of the examples. Each dictionary has two key: 'train' and 'valid.'

I'll really appreciate if someone could explain why I am getting the error I mentioned above. And while executing the code I printed the type of my matrix and vector and it says numpy array Therefore, I don't know why I am getting this error. Insights will be appreciated.

Comment: Try returning (snp,pos), y in your __getitem__

Comment: I tried that as well before posting the question but then I got the following error:AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'. I've edited my question to show you how I am calling my data generation script. Do you think I am doing something wrong there?

Comment: Ah sorry it needs to be a list, which should be [snp, pos], y , not a tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `__getitem__` method, you are returning a tuple of three elements, while it should be a list of inputs and a list of outputs, as a tuple, for example:

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    'Generate one batch of data'
    # Generate indexes of the batch
    indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]

    # Find list of IDs
    list_IDs_temp_snp = [self.list_IDs_snp[k] for k in indexes]
    list_IDs_temp_pos = [self.list_IDs_pos[k] for k in indexes]

    # Generate data
    snp,pos,y = self.__data_generation(list_IDs_temp_snp,list_IDs_temp_pos)

    return [snp, pos], y
```

Since you only have one output there is no need for a list.